# Regular expression takes unsual amount of time?

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, performance

Here's the code I'm running :

```
Dim descriptionMatches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(pageJSON, "\[\[(([\w]+[\s]*)+)\]\], (([\w]+[\s]*)+)\\n")
Console.WriteLine(descriptionMatches.Count)
```

Now, everything works fine until the last line. Looks like the MatchCollection.Count() method takes really long to execute, so long, I've run the program for more than 2 minutes...

Here's some additional information.

- When I cut the regex pattern to just `"\[\[(([\w]+[\s]*)+)\]\]"` I get 35 matches and it's seemingly instantaneous.
- When I use a for loop to parse through the MatchCollection, if I use a loop in the form of for i=0 to matchcollection.count, the loop doesn't get executed (like the regex is still trying to analyse the input string. And if I use a for each (the difference is that the latest uses an iterator) I get to about the 15th match before it freezes. Weird isn't it?
- Here's the a link to the string I'm trying to match, as you will see, it's not the longest string ever : [Wikipedia API result for SRS](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&titles=SRS&prop=revisions&rvprop=content)
- In the probable case where my pattern is the problem and you want to suggest me a new pattern, what I'm trying to match looks like this :

> [[Name of item]], description of item\n

I've used regular expressions a lot in the past and this has never happened to me. If someone knows what is the problem, could you please tell me what it is and how to fix it?

Comment: Tip: `[\w]` → `\w`, `[\s]` → `\s`. And try replacing both `(\w+\s*)+` with `(\w+\s+)*\w+`. And use a verbatim string `@"…\n"` so you don’t have to double-escape.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to match two `[[` followed by something followed by two `]]`. Make it simple for yourself:

```
\[\[([^][]+)\]\], (.*?)\\n\*
```

See it at work at http://regex101.com/r/kK5rO4

Explanation:

```
\[\[       find two literal [[ in a row
([^][]+)   match at least one character that is not ] or [ (note - the order matters)
           and "save" that match (so you can pull it out later)
\]\]       all the fun stops when you hit two closing brackets
           (but since the match already said "no closing brackets" there is no backtracking)
,          match comma followed by space
(.*?)      match the least amount you can until you get to…

\\n\*      literal \n* (both the \ and the * need a backslash to escape them
```

You need a `g` flag for a conventional regex to match "all instances" but I think that's taken care of by the rest of your code, effectively.

Comment: It started out simple, then `(.*)+?`? What?

Comment: Sorry - typo. Edited, and works now (see demo at link).

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what that ([^][]+). Isn't [^] supposed to mean the beginning of the string? And what does that []+ mean? I've never seen the square brackets used like this before.

Comment: It's tricky. A group of square brackets signals "any of the characters in this list". You can have single characters, or groups (for example `[a-z]` means "all characters from a to z inclusive". You can add a NOT with the caret `^`. "Anything except digits" could be `[^0-9]`. The tricky thing is to say "Anything that is not a close bracket" without it closing the expression. It MUST be the first character in the list - thus `[^]]` means "anything but close bracket". To be safe I wanted "anything not open or close bracket" which got me to `[^][]`. Make sense?

Answer (score 3):

Your regular expression leads to "[catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)", making it too complex.

Consider rewriting your regex to be more [possessive](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html).